# Erro gatilhos Postgresql closed

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have 2 tables ("reports" and "RA_log"), one for the user to record points with agglomeration and another that records the logs. I created a function to audit every time any change is made to the "reports" table.

```
CREATE TABLE Reports
(
report_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
report_user_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    report_location_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    report_number_people INT NOT NULL,
    report_mask VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    report_distance BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
report_observations VARCHAR(255),
report_date_time timestamp NOT NULL,
report_latitude VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
report_longitude VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE RA_log
(
    log_change_type CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
   log_user VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    log_date_occurrence TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
report_username VARCHAR NOT NULL,
report_quantity_people INTEGER
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audita_RA_log() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
INSERT INTO RA_log VALUES ('D', USER, now(), OLD.*);
RETURN OLD;
ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
INSERT INTO RA_log VALUES ('U', USER, now(), NEW.*);
RETURN NEW;
ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
INSERT INTO RA_log VALUES ('I', USER, now(), NEW.*);
RETURN NEW;
END IF;
RETURN NULL; --the result is ignored because the trigger is AFTER
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_log_RA
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON reports
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audita_RA_log();

INSERT INTO reports (report_username, report_location_name, report_quantity_people, report_mask, report_distance, report_observacoes, report_date_time, report_latitude, report_longitude)
VALUES ('Scooby', 'Lucky Lottery', 20, 'No', '1', 'Lots of people', '2021-06-22 4:10:25-07','-6.47926', '-35.4348' );
```

but when I'm going to enter some data. is returning the following error:
ERROR:  INSERT has more expressions than target columns
LINE 1: INSERT INTO RA_log VALUES ('D', USER, now(), OLD.*)
^
QUERY:  INSERT INTO RA_log VALUES ('D', USER, now(), OLD.*)
CONTEXT:  função PL/pgSQL audita_ra_log() linha 4 em comando SQL
SQL state: 42601

Comment: Please make sure your question title is also in English, and summarizes your question.

Answer (score 1):

it was like this, I modified some columns in the table RA_log.

```
CREATE TABLE RA_log
(
   change VARCHAR NOT NULL,
   changed_table VARCHAR NOT NULL,
   date_time_change TIMESTAMP,
   user_change VARCHAR NOT NULL
);

CREATE FUNCTION log_reports() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
   BEGIN
    INSERT INTO sys_log(change, table_changed, date_time_change, user_change)
    VALUES (TG_OP, TG_TABLE_NAME, now(), CURRENT_USER );
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER change_reports
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON reports
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE log_reports();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table `ra_log` has 5 columns, but your inserts statements are attempting to insert 13 columns: Type, User, date and the 10 columns from `Reports`. That is because old.* and new.* actually mean *each column from the table the trigger is fired on*. In this case all 10 columns from `Reports`. You have 2 options.

1. Refer directly to the columns defined in `reports`. So
   old.report_user_name, old.report_number_people (or new. as
   appropriate) that you want in `ra_log`.

```
create or replace function audita_ra_log() 
 returns trigger 
 language plpgsql 
as $$ 
begin
    if (tg_op = 'delete') then
        insert into ra_log values ('d', user, now(), old.report_id, old.report_user_name);
    else
         insert into ra_log values (lower(substr(tg_op,1,1)), user, now(), new.report_id, new.report_user_name);
    end if;
end;    
$$;
```

2. If you want all columns from `Reports` then discontinue the columns
   report_username, report_quantity_people and replace them by a single column of hstore or json. Change the trigger accordingly.

```
CREATE TABLE ra_log( 
       log_change_type CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
     , log_user VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     , log_date_occurrence TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
     , reports_value json
);

create or replace function audita_ra_log() 
 returns trigger 
 language plpgsql 
as $$ 
begin
    if (tg_op = 'delete') then
        insert into ra_log values ('d', user, now(), row_to_json(old.*));
    else
         insert into ra_log values (lower(substr(tg_op,1,1)), user, now(), row_to_json(new.*));
    end if;
end;    
$$; 

If keeping the complete row I prefer [hstore][1] as it keeps actual column names, but json is probably the more common.
```

Comment: If it solver your issue then please accept it. This helps future  questioners having the same issue and removes the question from the unanswered queue. Please do not leave successfully answered questions in an active/unanswered state. If it didn't solve your issue the what remains?